# 2FA: This Mac must be approved - but from which device?

Tags: mac, icloud, keychain, two-factor-authentication

Another 2-Factor Annoyance: I'm getting this message:

[image]

<sup>"This Mac must be approved from one of your other devices to use iCloud Keychain."</sup>

Does this mean one *specific* other device? Or does it just mean I need to initiate some steps to authorize from *any* of my other devices? (And if so, what are those steps?)

These instructions are vague. Also, I don't know why the Mac, of all things, my main hub device, which is stationary and least likely to be stolen or compromised, suddenly needs to be approved from some mobile device (that I would grant less authority if up to me). I never intended to set up iCloud Keychain anyway, and I don't know what triggered this. I also don't know if resetting the iCloud Keychain that I may or may not be using on some other device would help or just cause more problems. Hopefully someone can advise.

Answer (score 3):

This message is appearing because your Mac isn't properly connected to iCloud Keychain and is now trying to connect. Regardless of what caused this...

1. "your other devices" refers to any other device that is connected to iCloud Keychain.
2. If you have no other devices that use iCloud Keychain, simply press "Reset iCloud Keychain." If your Mac was previously connected, the data is also stored locally and will be re-uploaded.

If you have an iPhone/iPad/another Mac with iCloud Keychain switched on, you should receive a prompt to approve this Mac. If you don't, try restarting it and turning it on again.

If you don't have another computer, or are having trouble completing those steps, reset iCloud Keychain then set it up again to ensure everything is working properly. If you don't want to use iCloud Keychain, I still recommend turning it on and then off again to ensure whatever glitch caused this has been resolved.

---

You can read more about iCloud Keychain here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085